# Switch issue - only one option visible

Tags: android, switch-statement

I want to use switch in an android application. I tried it but main issue is

- if i have selected ON , it won't display off text.
- if i have selected OFF , it won't display on text.

Off text is not displayed but we can select OFF by clicking in black area of switch.

**Code**

```
<Switch android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
android:height="50dp"
android:text="ON OFF"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:switchMinWidth="50sp"
android:switchPadding="50sp"/>
```

On State

[image]

Off state

[image]

How i can display both text at the same time?
Can i change text of switch for both state ON/OFF?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please clarify your question if the state of the switch is off should the text next to post ongoogle ,facebook etc... say off ?

Comment: can u update question with layout design code?

Comment: You can take a custom drawable with on off text and set it as a background of toggle button.

Comment: @ilovepjs : no it's totally different control.

Comment: Plz give a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which creates a custom widget to mimic the Switch control. I'm using Xamarin, but this code can easily be translated to Java.

SwitchImageView.cs:

```
public class SwitchImageView : RelativeLayout {
        private View view;

        private bool isChecked;
        private int imageResourceIdOn = Resource.Drawable.switch_on;
        private int imageResourceIdOff = Resource.Drawable.switch_off;

        public SwitchImageView(Context context): base(context) {
            Init ();
        }

        public SwitchImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) {
            Init ();
        }

        public SwitchImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle) {
            Init ();
        }

        private void Init () {
            var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ApplicationContext.Activity.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            layoutInflater.Inflate (RPR.Mobile.Resource.Layout.SwitchImageView, this, true);

            this.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                Checked = !Checked;
            };
        }

        public int ImageResourceIdOn { 
            get {
                return imageResourceIdOn;
            }
            set {
                imageResourceIdOn = value;
                if (isChecked) {
                    this.SetBackgroundResource (value);
                }
            }
        }

        public int ImageResourceIdOff { 
            get {
                return imageResourceIdOff;
            }
            set {
                imageResourceIdOff = value;
                if (!isChecked) {
                    this.SetBackgroundResource (value);
                }
            }
        }

        public string TextOn { 
            get {
                return this.FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.switch_on_text).Text;
            }
            set {
                this.FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.switch_on_text).Text = value;
            }
        }

        public string TextOff { 
            get {
                return this.FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.switch_off_text).Text;
            }
            set {
                this.FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.switch_off_text).Text = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Checked { 
            get {
                return isChecked;
            }
            set {
                isChecked = value;
                this.SetBackgroundResource (value ? ImageResourceIdOn : ImageResourceIdOff);
                this.FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.switch_on_text).SetTextColor (value ? Color.White : Color.Black);
                this.FindViewById <TextView> (Resource.Id.switch_off_text).SetTextColor (value ? Color.Black : Color.White);
                if (CheckedChange != null) {
                    CheckedChange (this, value);
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<bool> CheckedChange;
    }
```

SwitchImageView.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switch_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_off_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="On"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch_on_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Off"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one made by 2 Standard buttons and a LinearLayout. There are bunch of xml files to import but it works perfect on all versions and very easy to use. Check the following Github Page

[Preview](http://imgbox.com/WdGluJGK)

[Custom Switch With 2 Buttons](https://github.com/sekizbit/android-custom-switch)

### usage

1. Copy XML files under res/drawable to your project's res/drawable folder.
2. Copy LinearLayout from layout.xml to your layout file.
3. Copy values from values/colors.xml and values/dimens to your own files.
4. Initilize the switch with following code

`SekizbitSwitch mySwitch = new SekizbitSwitch(findViewById(R.id.sekizbit_switch));
        mySwitch.setOnChangeListener(new SekizbitSwitch.OnSelectedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnSelectedChange(SekizbitSwitch sender) {
                if(sender.getCheckedIndex() ==0 )
                {
                    System.out.println("Left Button Selected");
                }
                else if(sender.getCheckedIndex() ==1 )
                {
                    System.out.println("Right Button Selected");
                }
            }
        });`